# How does Whirlwind Strike interact with True Strike?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, attack-roll

I have a Barbarian with Runescarred dedication. He is *[hasted](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147)* and casts *[true strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=345)* and then makes a *[whirlwind strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=170)*. Whirlwind strike takes 3 actions but is essentially one strike (from feat name and narrative perspective), however, you need to "make a melee Strike against each enemy within your melee reach" when determining hit success. So, does the Barbarian roll twice to hit for all surrounding enemies, or roll twice to hit for first targeted enemy only?

Comment: Tangentially, you might not be using [haste](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147) quite right. The extra action can only be used to Stride or Strike, which excludes it being used for Whirlwind Strike or True Strike. However, your GM may be ruling otherwise, and there are other ways to True Strike and Whirlwind Strike in the same turn (such as via Quickened Casting), so the question is still very valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Only the first.**

Whirlwind attack mechanically **is not** one single attack but a bunch of attacks as the text clarify.

> You attack all nearby adversaries. **Make a melee Strike against each enemy** within your melee reach. **Each attack** counts toward your multiple attack penalty, but do not increase your penalty until you have made all **your attacks**.

The name of the feat let assume that is one attack for all...and narratively speaking it is cool to think you are doing one big swing and try to hit them all but mechanically you roll once against every enemy and this means that you are making a strike (so an attack) against every enemy one at time.

So we are talking about attacks...and since we are talking about attacks *true strike* works only on the first

> **The next time you make an attack roll** before the end of your turn, roll the attack twice and use the better result. [...]

Comment: You are correct, but the terminology needs cleaned up. The second printing clarifies the difference between an attack and an attack roll. True strike applies to the next attack roll -- not the next attack. Whirlwind Attack has you perform multiple Strikes and therefore multiple attack rolls.